# Código VBA para obter valores dentro de HTML

Tags: html, html5, vba

Quero recolher dois valores de um HTML através de VBA. A informação '40 New' e o '$19.95'. O meu código consegue obter o '$19.95', mas na iteração seguinte faz overwrite e fica com o '$17.38'.

[image: HTML to parse]

```
`Set QuestionList = html.getElementById("olp_feature_div")
Set Questions = QuestionList.Children

For Each Question In Questions

If Question.className = "a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small" Then

Set QuestionFields = Question.all
For Each QuestionField In QuestionFields

If QuestionField.className = "a-color-price" Then

votes = Replace(QuestionField.innerText, "votes", "")
votes = Replace(votes, "vote", "")
Cells(RowNumber, 2).Value = Trim(votes)
End If
```

Comment: Não entendi, você quer parar a repetição no primeiro elemento encontrado?

Comment: Sim, neste caso, mas o critério não pode ser a posição, porque por vezes o '40 New' é o segundo elemento. Se houver uma forma de obter o elemento dentro da classe que contém a string 'new', o problema fica resolvido. Não sei é como o fazer.

Comment: você poderia colocar o código completo que você tem? E também qual é o site que você está usando, pois pelo que consegui encontrar, se trata de uma página da Amazon, até consegui pegar o `40 new`, porém não encontrei a *class* `a-color-price` dentro da *div* `olp_feature_div`